# Is it possible to use the framework behind Metro UI to make Exposé?

Tags: desktop-application, mac, windows-8, metro

Is it possible to use the framework behind the Windows 8 Metro UI to make Exposé-like application for Windows? I tried Mac and I really like this feature, on another side i like that I can drag the screen from the top of the screen into the Metro UI, but that is completely useless. So imagine if it is possible to use this functionality in a Exposé-like application for windows.

Is it even feasible? If not, maybe at a later stage? I am a programming rookie, but it could be a fun project.

Thanks in advance for any answers, suggestions and information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible.

All WinRT applications are completely isolated from other applications and OS. Only specific APIs are available for them and neither of those allow what you would like to do. It could be possible, but we are talking about low-level OS hacking. Not something rookie could handle.